# Windows 10 unable to boot, failure to repair loop-refer to srttrail.txt inside

Tags: windows-10

UDPATE2: This has been SOLVED by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2f-GorXWkoc

It shows how to copy the registry hives from the Regback folder to the config folder. The Regback folder contains backups of the Registry Hives in the config folder which may have been corrupted during the update.

UPDATE: I have an AMD processor. dism.txt output pasted here: https://pastebin.com/XLuLQpc0

ISSUE: We have a relatively new (couple months) Windows 10 HP Computer that was suddenly unable to boot into the OS. Unable to enter Safe Mode. Automatic Repair failed. System Restore failed.

After trying a bunch of solutions, Self-Repair system referred an srttrail.txt file to me, which I copied to a drive and have posted below. I'm not sure what to glean from it. Can anyone else:

### Session details

System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0
Windows directory = C:\WINDOWS
AutoChk Run = 0
Number of root causes = 0

### Test Performed:

Name: Check for updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System disk test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk failure diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 47 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 1656 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 47 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Target OS test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 187 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Volume content check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 469 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Boot manager diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System boot log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 16 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Event log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 78 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Internal state check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 31 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Check for pending package install
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x4
Time taken = 2422 ms

### ---------------------------

Comment: So all tests passed except the test which tests if an update is pending.  You can use `dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` to remove the pending updates.  [Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/48d20da9-0535-462f-b177-f30f48992203/how-to-removing-a-pending-update-that-is-preventing-a-successful-boot?forum=w7itprogeneral).  Do you have an Intel or AMD processor, update your question, don't leave a comment.

Comment: Question updated. It's an AMD. I did the dism.exe command and received an Error code #2, Unable to Access Image. The dism.txt output is pasted in the original post.

Comment: Did you by chance install the January update?

Comment: Probably? The updates were automatic. It's not my machine, but my sister's. I attempted a System Restore to January 3rd, but the restore apparently didn't work.

Comment: You need to use the correct drive letter.  It might or might not be C.  Depends on what other drives you have connected.  `DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` should revert the pending update, but it would really be helpful, if you could determine if the incompatible patch was being installed or not.

Comment: C is definitely the correct drive where Windows was installed. Also, according to the System Restore logs, January 9th two critical Windows updates were installed. I'm assuming Restore points would not have been created if they weren't. Also, I ran the DISM command again and received an error of #3. Unable to Access Image.
Link to second DISM log: https://pastebin.com/Qxy845Ej

Comment: Interesting, same here from a client's workstation.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting the update.  Got here from searching for the same error message in SrtTrail.txt after my registry was corrupted by Windows Update.  The video solved my problem as well.  I had no idea that Windows Update saves a registry backup.

Comment: I'm so glad this topic helped you Lehiester!